# iPad showing images from array

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

I had an array with 400 strings, each representing the name of an image. I have to show them as tiles like that in a gallery application. In the small version with 20 images, I used the following way.

1. Downloaded the images asynchronously.
2. Used ImageView+ScrollView combination and a for loop to add each imageview to the scrollview.

But I know it is not the right way when considering memory issues. How should I do this, any available frameworks? Also, how should I do it without using a framework?

Comment: You should take a look at UICollectionView class https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the UI, the collection view is made for exactly that purpose.

This is an older but nice tutorial that tells you how to do that within a table view. However, you can simply adopt the same logic to the data source of a collection view.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

(I learned it from that tutorial myself. But as I implemented my case well before the collection view as introduced by Apple, I simply displayd an array of image views in each table cell. Now that the collection view is available I would scrap my (rather complicated) solution and go for the collection instead, when ever I have a chance for refactoring my old app. )

Comment: http://maniacdev.com/2012/12/example-creating-a-magazine-rack-view-using-uicollectionview has a good sample to work out.